# OpenAPI3: how to send JSON as part of a request

Tags: http, swagger, openapi

I want to model the following HTTP Request in openAPI3:

```
POST /users HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.65.1.70:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de-AT,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://10.65.1.70/sites/config-sites/user-config.html
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ...
Origin: http://10.65.1.70
Content-Length: 42
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1

{"name":"openAPITest","password":"noPassHere"}
```

I currently have this:

```
/users/:
    post:
          summary: adds user
          parameters:
            - name: name
              required: true
              in: header
              schema:
                type: string
            - name: password
              required: true
              in: header
              schema:
                type: string
          responses:
            "201":
              description: OK
            "400":
              description: Wrong Format
```

What I'm missing is a way to correctly pass the login information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in the end:

```
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      summary: login credentials
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: string
            example: 
              {"name":"openAPITest","password":"noPassHere"}
```

Note that openAPI automatically escapes the " " in the provided json